# SVN: Can you merge multiple trunks to multiple corresponding branches?

Tags: svn, version-control, merge, branching-and-merging

The title may not be the best to understand the problem, but I hope the following text can do it:

The client I'm working on uses a multiple trunk structure to split components and dependencies. so something like this:

project A

- trunk
- branches

project B

- trunk
- branches

And so on...

Now, since you need both A and B to run the full application, sometimes you make changes to both of them, and you can commit everything at the same time, even if working in two different trunks, the commit gets the same revision for all the trunks, and running **svn log -r REV_NUMBER** in all trunks, I get all the files that I have changed.

What I would like to do now, is pick this commit and merge it to a corresponding branch in each of the projects in only one step. At the moment, the only way I can do this is to merge each trunk for each project individually.

Something like: Pick the revision number N for all projects A and B (or more) in the Trunk and merge the changes to the same projects in Branch X.

Comment: `cvs log -r REVNUM`? wut? Is this `svn log -r REVNUM`? Do you run `svn` or `cvs`? Huge difference!

Comment: Yes, SVN! Really sorry! Fixed it!